# Waiting for response from 127.0.0.1

Tags: localhost

I'm using a workstation with Windows 7 Pro 64bit; IE version 9.0.8112.16421 (update ver. 9.0.18).
I'm using a local facility (WAMP or AMPPS) and a WordPress installation for website testing. 
I have Apache and MySQL running fine.

But using Internet Explorer, the requests to localhost (127.0.0.1) get no response - not just slow - they never resolve.

**The localhost request will resolve successfully only when a second request is made immediately or within a few seconds** (like a slow double-click).

Sometimes issuing a refresh (F5) is successful with localhost if done within a few seconds of the first request (especially useful if the selected menu function no longer appears available during localhost page change request). It doesn't seem to be a Firewall issue (whether off or on).

What might be responsible for this behavior?
Has anyone else experienced this and resolved it?

Comment: A proxy in your setings?

Comment: @ott please explain?

Comment: @spainters firewall shouldn't be affecting you on the same machine. 127.0.0.1 should always resolve, no matter what is in hosts--unless IE is set to go through a proxy for everything. Are you sure Apache is running and bound to port 80 (use `telnet` to check)?

Comment: I have a similar setup (W7x64P - Lounge VC11 Apache2.4.7) and similar problems.  From time to time Chrome, IE and FireFox are very slow on a localhost.  They are fine on a remote server.  Safari and Opera don't have this problem.  I've cut my httpd.conf to the minimum.  Tried many things in hosts.  Sometimes it hangs forever, and sometimes it hangs for just a long time.  By disabling or re-enabling WiFi I can get it to give up.  Once I get a page to load it works for a short time again and again, but if I wait a few minutes chances are it will hang again.  I must say I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your host file is corrupt. Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\ and find your host file.  Check that localhost is listed like so:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

And make sure it is not commented out with a "#".

Comment: Thanks, had already done that with no effect. And besides, I believe localhost is resolved by DNS, as of Win7, per MS. Any other ideas?

Comment: Localhost is hardcoded in the windows resolver. No entry in the host file is needed.